# Ninject Bind IIdentityMessageService twice

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-identity-2, ninject.web.mvc

I hope you are doing well with everything.

I am trying to seperate the asp.net identity UserManger implementation from the default implementation that comes with the project template.
For DI I am using Ninject (I am new to Ninject)

Now I have something like this...

```
 kernel.Bind<UserManager<User>>().To<UserManager>().InRequestScope();
 kernel.Bind<IUserTokenProvider<User, string>>().ToMethod(x =>
 {
     var provider = OwinConfig.DataProtectionProvider;
     return new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
 }).InRequestScope();


 kernel.Bind<SignInManager>()
       .ToSelf()
       .InRequestScope();
```

I am trying to register the SmsService and EmailService that implement IIdentityMessageService

**I am doing something like this ---- and it is not working with ninject**

```
kernel.Bind<IIdentityMessageService>().To(typeof (SmsService)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IIdentityMessageService>().To(typeof (EmailService)).InRequestScope();
```

> Error activating IIdentityMessageService More than one matching
>   bindings are available.
>
> ......
>
> Suggestions:  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for
>   IIdentityMessageService only once.

Now as said before I moved the usermanager to a seperate library and the constructor for my UserManger is

```
public UserManager(Context context, IIdentityMessageService emailService, 
    IIdentityMessageService smsService, IUserTokenProvider<User, string> tokenProvider = null)
    : base(new UserStore(context))
```

So my question is, how can I achieve to inject IIdentityMessageService twice or how to construct UserManager with ninject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [named bindings](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/e09664f4c3db5c2d1599cd11dbea6ae28d16f1ff/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingNamedSyntax.cs):

```
kernel.Bind<IIdentityMessageService>().To(typeof (SmsService)).Named("Sms");
kernel.Bind<IIdentityMessageService>().To(typeof (EmailService)).Named("Email");
```

And then resolve it via attributes:

```
public UserManager(Context context, 
                  [Named("Email")] IIdentityMessageService emailService,
                  [Named("Sms")] IIdentityMessageService smsService, 
                  IUserTokenProvider<User, string> tokenProvider = null)
   : base(new UserStore(context))
```